# matching grouping symbol finder

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to write a program that takes as input an arithmetic expression. The program outputs whether the expression contains matching grouping symbols.

> Like  {7 * (3+5)} has a matching grouping symol

Clearly it involves Stack but I have no idea how to use stack in a c++ program.

Comment: Ok, feel free to write this program. Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: yes @alexeykuzmin0 sir definitely , give me some idea "how to implement stack in the program"
and "how to find matching grouping symbols"
i'll be grateful

Comment: Try reading wikipedia articles for stack and regular expressions. BTW, maybe regular expressions are an overkill here and `std::string::find` will be enough. Also, please check the Stackoverflow FAQ on how to ask questions. We'll be happy to see you here with any specific question.

Comment: You can probably do it without a stack. Just count the brackets. +1 with open bracket, -1 for close. If count = 0, success. Just need to handle the cases like `}x+1{`. That would give count = 0, but is obviously wrong. There is a work-around....